# Random forest classifier + bag of words leads to size issue

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, random-forest

I built a model to predict a vendor name based on a receipt.

For this I use a bag-of-words approach and a random forest classifier. The code looks like below.

```
X = df['taggunResponse']
y = df['label']

count_vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), binary =True, max_df = 0.03 ,min_df = 10, lowercase = False)
count_vect.fit(X)
X_counts = count_vect.transform(X)


X_train_counts, X_test_counts, y_train, y_test, filenames_train, filenames_test  = train_test_split(X_counts, y, filenames, test_size=0.23, random_state = 0)

clf  = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20, random_state=0).fit(X_train_counts, y_train)
```

If I pickle objects, I see their size on disk as:

y ~ 200 kB

X_train_counts ~ 2 MB

clf ~ 2 GB

How can my classifier be so much larger than the data that was used to train it? Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: which version are you using? and check this out: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32644/randomforest-reasons-for-memory-usage-consumption

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Python 3.7.4 and  sklearn 0.21.3
I understand that number of trees and size of input data both influence the size of the model, but in this case the model is 25 times larger than even the size of the data multiplied by the number of trees, which seems wrong.

Comment: here is a similar problem: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/8358/prohibitive-size-of-random-forest-when-saved-to-disk